# Test users can't install or use a google chat app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat, google-appsheet

How can I allow tests users from outside  my workspace (different email domain) to use my chat app?

- The Chat app was created in google apps script and linked to a GCP project, the app works but just for users in my workspace

Hi, I have a google chat app that is going to be used by people in my workspace and some users with gmail.com accounts, I've added all the users to the test users lists but still only people inside my workspace are able to use the app, users with gmail.com account can't install the app (they don't see it listed) and clicking on cards buttons does nothing, I have tried publishing the app but one of the recommendations from google is this:

1. If your application is for Personal use only:

The app is not shared with anyone else or will be used by fewer than 100 users. Hence, you can continue using the app by bypassing the unverified app warning during sign-in. It is recommended, however, that your project’s publish state is set to testing and continue to use your app under testing mode.

Which exactly describe my app and requirements

I added all my users to the GCP project users list, still users outside my workspace can't use the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Google Chat, so the answer is that there isn't much you can do at the moment. Just wait until Google fixes it.

You could help expedite the resolution by voting and leaving comments in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297141187) to make Google prioritize this matter.

*Note: I am the creator of that issue link.*